# Problem trying to display a list of inputs when updating a record

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-hooks, put

I am practicing react with spring boot, I have a problem rendering inputs when I want to update the information

```
const {id} = useParams();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{id: '', mobileNumber: "", supplierNumber: id}]);
    const history = useHistory();

    //React Hook form estructura
    const {register, handleSubmit, setValue, formState: { errors }} = useForm({resolver: yupResolver(schema)});


    useEffect(() => {
        //Si existe un id en el parametro de la url entonces realizamos el fetch
        
        if(id) {
            const fetchData = async () => {
                try {
                    const resp = await axios.get(`${SUPPLIERS_ENDPOINT}/${id}`);

                    if(resp.data !== null) {
                        const {name, nif, email, webPage, mobileNumbers} = resp.data;
                        //Con estos setValues seteamos los values de los inputs del formulario, para que aparezcan rellenos con la informacion que nos devolvio el metodo get
                        setValue("name", name);  
                        setValue("nif", nif); 
                        setValue("webPage", webPage); 
                        setValue("email", email);  
                 *****I think the problem is here*************
                        mobileNumbers.map((m,i) => {
                            if(i !== 0) {
                                setInputList([...inputList, {id: m.id, mobileNumber: m.mobileNumber, supplierNumber: id}]);
                            } else {
                                setInputList([{id: m.id, mobileNumber: m.mobileNumber, supplierNumber: id}]);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    setErrores(error);
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
            fetchData();
        }
    }, []);
```

The problem is that the useState only saves me the initial value and the last value of the setInputList.

Output:

[image]

[image]

but my desired output would be this

```
0: {id: 119, mobileNumber: 951, supplierNumber: "117"}

1: {id: 118, mobileNumber: 6789, supplierNumber: "117"}
```

Comment: What does `resp.data` look like?

Comment: Looks like there is multiple entities with different `id` but you're not doing things like `setValue("name", name);` in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! it was just change to this in the useEffect:

```
mobileNumbers.forEach((m,i) => {
    if(i !== 0) {
        setMobNumsList(i => [...i, {id: m.id, mobileNumber: m.mobileNumber,supplierNumber:id}]);
    } else {
        setMobNumsList([{id: m.id, mobileNumber: m.mobileNumber, supplierNumber: id}]);
    }
});
```